# Not receiving the key to the sewers in Stardew Valley

Tags: stardew-valley

I have donated 60 items to Gunther and am playing on Xbox, so I  have no mods or hacks. For some reason I didn't get the sewer key the day following reaching 60 items donated. I even did the magnifying glass thing and I have done all the cutscenes to allow it. To clarify, I now have 63 items in total, just in case my info is wrong.

Comment: Are you playing a solo game or multiplayer? There used to be (and still might be) a bug where you didn't receive the key until the owner had talked to Gunther.

Answer (score 0):

Donating 60 items to Gunther should trigger the cutscene receiving the key in single player the morning after the 60th donation. But on Multiplayer one must talk to Gunther first (it is not automatic).

The Rusty Key will be displayed in the Wallet section of the player's inventory I think so check if you have received it just in case.